# RVO or automatic move

Tags: c++, c++17, move, return-value-optimization

Consider the following function.

```
std::string foo()
{
  const std::string s = "hello";
  return s;
}
```

`clang-tidy` suggests to remove `const` qualifier as is prevents an automatic move. Is this suggestion valid as there shouldn't be a move at all due to RVO?

Comment: I think I remember RVO can't happen if the move isn't possible...

Comment: I am not sure, I've read otherwise in several places ([e.g.](https://www.bfilipek.com/2017/01/const-move-and-rvo.html#returning-const))

Comment: This is NRVO, Named RVO, because you're returning a named object. NRVO is not mandatory (as opposed to RVO and some other forms of copy-elision). If NRVO cannot be applied, then you'd get a copy instead of a move because of that `const`.